# The translation of measurable function

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $u$: $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a bounded measurable function. Define 
$$
u_\epsilon(x):=u(x+\epsilon)
$$
My question: Do we have
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}u_\epsilon(x) = u(x)
$$
a.e. $x\in\mathbb R$? It looks to me it is trivially true and I even think it may hold everywhere. But I feel uncomfortable for this... Can anybody help me to look at it?

Comment: This holds at continuity points of $u$: $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} u_\epsilon (x) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} u(x+\epsilon) = u(x)$ if and only if $u$ is continuous at $x$.

Comment: Think continuity versus measurability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example, if $$u(x)=\chi_{\mathbb Q}(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x\in \mathbb Q\\ 0 & \text{else}\end{cases}$$

Then the limit $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} u_\epsilon(x)$$

does not exist, but $u$ is a measurable function.